# Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ be measurable and $B \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $m^*(B)=0$. Show using the definition that $A \cup B$ is a measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ be measurable and $B \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $m^*(B)=0$ where $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure. Show using the definition that $A \cup B$ is a measurable set.

The definition seems to be the Carathèodory criterion so $A \cup B$ is measurable provided that for any $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ $$m^*(E)= m^*(E \cap (A \cup B)) + m^*(E \setminus(A \cup B))$$

From $A$ being measurable I have that for any $F \subset \Bbb R^n$ $$m^*(F)=m^*(F \cap A) + m^*(F \setminus A)$$

but not sure how to approach the union of $A \cup B$?

Comment: Maybe they mean the definition that involves coverings by boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m^*(E \cap (A\cup B)) + m^*(E \setminus (A\cup B))$$ $$\leq [m^{*}(E \cap A)+m^{*}(E \cap B)]+ m^*(E \setminus A)$$ $$=m^{*}(E)$$ since $m^{*}(E \cap B) \leq m^{*}(B)=0$. The reverse inequality always holds.